# Why this happen, javascript sparse array uninitiated

Tags: javascript

[image]

It seems the value is OK, but I don't know if this kind of programming is OK in javascript.

Comment: What's point of having such array?

Comment: An array starts at zero, and when you set something in the 32 index, the 32 (including zero) indices before that is set to `undefined`

Comment: You seem to be asking two difference questions... what do you really want to know?

Comment: @Vohuman 32 is a key, I should use "32" then the array output in devtools is just like a normal array, but I'm not sure use number as the key is OK in javascript

Comment: If `32` is a _key_ then  you  probably need an object not an array.

Comment: Array indices are always numeric.

Comment: @FelixKling is this kind of use will cause some problem, so the devtools notice me that some array member is undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to avoid this kind of things. In my opinion it's better to use push to create array which you can go through with for loops.

Problem with this is that if you create things like this and then wanna do something with data you would end up with because you have to skip undefines.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i] != undefined) {
     // do something here
   }
}
```

When you get other developers on the code, it generates considerable number of WTF moments. I had to work with code which was using this kind of assignment of values in arrays so that index always corresponds with ID and it is nightmare to maintain and figure out what is going on.

Also the length of the arr will be reported 'incorrectly' because you only had one value inside, but length is 33.

If you need ID's or something, you can use

```
var arr = [];
arr.push({"id":32, "value": "this is element with id attribute 32"});
```

Edit:

If you need to retrieve something which has ID 32 in this case, you would do

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (arr[i].id === 32) {
     // do something here
   }
}
```